# How to display the list of processes especifically running Application programs in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

How to display the list of processes specifically running Application programs in C# Console Application

I made a console application just like a task manager, in which the users can start, view and terminate process.
Then there are options for viewing processes, View all, View Running apps, View Background processes, and System process.
I already accomplished the first option which the "Viewl all" option, but I can't accomplish the other 3 options.

My codes are below...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace taskManager
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a;
            intro:
            Console.WriteLine("OPTIONS:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Start Process");
            Console.WriteLine("2. View Process");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Terminate a Process");
            Console.Write("Enter Option:");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (a == "1") goto start;
            if (a == "2") goto view;
            if (a == "3") goto terminate;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option!");
            goto intro;
            start:
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Process name:");
                a = Console.ReadLine();
                Process.Start(a);
                goto intro;
            }
            view:
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("OPTIONS for View:");
                Console.WriteLine("a. View all");
                Console.WriteLine("b. View Applications");
                Console.WriteLine("c. View Background process");
                Console.WriteLine("d. View System Process");
                Console.Write("Enter Option:");
                a=Console.ReadLine();
                if (a == "a") goto a;
                if (a == "b") goto b;
                a:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processes");
                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                    Console.WriteLine("No. Of Pocess: {0}", processes.Length);
                    foreach (Process process in processes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
                    }
                    goto intro;
                }
    //This is where the unaccomplished options
        b:Apps
        c:background Process
        d:System process
            }
            terminate:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter process name:");
                a = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(a))
                {
                    process.Kill();

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Process terminated!");
                goto intro;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606) by Raymond Chen

Comment: I know the differences about processes the problem is to display them using console application in c#

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void ListAllProcess()
    {
        int processCount = 0;
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

        // view All running process
        foreach (Process process in processList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} <> ID: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.Id);
            processCount += 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Total Process: {0} ", processCount);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // view All running process..
        ListAllProcess();

        try
        {
            // for Start a new Process
            Console.Write("\n\nDrag-Drop or enter a full path of a executable file: ");
            string applicationPath = Console.ReadLine();
            Process.Start(applicationPath);

            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is started.", applicationPath);

            // This start program itself. Don't try this...
            // string appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath);
            Console.Write("\n\n\n");
            ListAllProcess();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", ex);
        }


        try
        {
            // for kill a running Process
            Console.Write("\n\nEnter a Process ID:");
            int processID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Process.GetProcessById(processID).Kill();
            Console.WriteLine("Process '{0}' died.", processID);
            Console.Write("\n\n\n");
            ListAllProcess();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", ex);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```